# how to create/join a namespace in a room on socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

I would like to use the `namespaces` in `room`'s `socket.io` features.

I know this [usefull reminder](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) about rooms where we can see:

1. A way to emit to sockets on a namespace's room
   `io.of('namespace').in('room').emit('event_name', data)`
2. A way to get a list of sockets in a namespace's room
   `io.of('namespace').clients('room')`

But this page desn't provide us the way to `create/join` a `socket` to a specific `namespace` in a specific `room`.

How to do that? I have try the following example without any success:

```
socket.join('city').in('district');
io.of('district').clients('/city'); // get []
io.of('/district').clients('/city'); // get []
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't join/leave namespaces. The namespace is part of the url when you first connect

For example, connecting to `"http://localhost/district"` would connect to the `"district"` namespace.

On the server, you can join rooms in that namespace like this:

```
io.of('/district').on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.join('city');
});
```